# Inventory Spreadsheet - Send email when cell value = "Expired" and populate email with info from table

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

UPDATE

I have reworked my code to look like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call notify
End Sub

Sub notify()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Range("N2:N502")
       If (rng.Value = "Expired") Then
           Call mymacro(rng.Address)
       End If
    Next rng
End Sub
Private Sub mymacro(theValue As String)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Dim myAddress As String
    Dim myChemical As String
    myAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A2:Q502"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Expired", Range("N2:N502"), 0), 15)
    myChemical = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A2:Q502"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Expired", Range("N2:N502"), 0), 3)
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Hello" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This email is to let you know that you have an expired reference standard" & vbNewLine & _
              "The Reference Standard that has expired is: " & myChemical & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Thank you," & vbNewLine & _
              "Spreadsheet Manager"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = myAddress
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Expired Reference Standard"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This new code now populates the emails with the correct fields, but it is getting stuck on the first entry that equals "Expired" in column N. It knows that there are multiple instances of "Expired" because when I change `myChemical` in the message to `theValue` multiple emails populate with different cell values. Is there a way to fix the code to avoid this error as is, or would I have to add a For-Next statement into the code?

Answer (score 0):

That's an ambitious project. You don't need the code to be continuously running if you have it triggered from a Worksheet_Change event. You can use that event to "watch" just the contents of specific rows, columns or ranges, and run the code when a cell in the watched range is changed by the user. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

The Worksheet_Change event runs in the Sheet module and uses the concept of the "target" range, which is the range or cell that triggered the macro to run. If it is a single cell, you now have the address of that cell and from there you can deduce the row number and get other data in that row, or data related to that cell dependent on your sheet layout.

You can now to construct the body text with the details you need.

Comment: This hasn't seemed to be the case with my spreadsheet. The cells that the macro is dependent on are dependent on formulas themselves, and when I update the cells that lead into that formula, the macro doesn't seem to automatically run

Comment: Then watch the cells that  contribute to the formula.